# Is async @RenderBody possible in mvc.net 6 vnext?

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I play around with mvc.net vnext and I read several posts about the possibility to use @RenderBody async but I never found a tutorial how to do this.

So what I have a _Layout.cshtml with a navigation bar.
Inside this bar I have several links to pages like:

```
<li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" ><i class="material-icons">home</i></a></li>
```

now after a click on that link, the page does a full postback...thats normal.

But as I wrote, if I remember right, there is an option to only load the new content in an async way in MVC6 without using self written javascript stuff.

Do you have some resources / tutorials?

Thanks :)

Comment: async in this context has nothing to do with ajax calls. those are two different things. I think you are missing concepts here.

Comment: clicking a link results in a get request, it is incorrect to say it does postback. sounds like you are interested in single page applications which can be implemented using things like AngularJS and web api. in MVC 6 the major change is that web api controllers and mvc controllers are the same thing whereas in previous versions they were different but similar things